# How to allocate more native memory in android?

Tags: android, memory-management

I'm trying to perform a flip animation in my application when a textview is clicked.

This is the memory information for my application

```
** MEMINFO in pid 1497 [com.example.android] **
                native   dalvik    other    total
        size:    36372    11911      N/A    48283
   allocated:    24025     6903      N/A    30928
        free:      646     5008      N/A     5654
       (Pss):     3330     8732    21309    33371
(shared dirty):   1456     4100     3272     8828
(priv dirty):     3256     6828    19300    29384

Objects
       Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
 AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
      Assets:        2    AssetManagers:        2
Local Binders:       10    Proxy Binders:       15
Death Recipients:    1
OpenSSL Sockets:     0

SQL
        heap:        0       memoryUsed:        0
pageCacheOverflo:    0  largestMemAlloc:        0


Asset Allocations
zip:/data/app/com.example.android-1.apk:/resources.arsc: 17K
```

I'm getting this error in the LogCat

```
06-13 11:12:49.005: E/dalvikvm-heap(1497): 1200000-byte external allocation 
too large for this process.
```

I think its, probably, because I have only `646kb` free. But it can be inferred from the native memory "size" that more native memory can be allocated. Why doesn't the VM allocate more memory? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android  .  I think the `free` field is free space of the current NDK malloc arena, which can be expanded.  The summary you're showing is only one process. Android has much more going on.  Note the use of `procrank` at the link above to see the bigger picture. You will probably have to find ways to release other memory (bitmaps, e.g.) to make room for this allocation.

Comment: @Gene I've gone through that link previously. Also, I understand that there are other processes using memory. But, if you look at the size of application process, more native memory should be allocated to it. I even tried analyzing hprof file, but I think MAT only analyzes dalvik heap memory.